# Forward slash in a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I have the code below.

```
{
    var custname= "@1";
    var file = "c:/temp/"+ custname + ".txt";
    var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.CreateTextFile(file, true, false);
    fh.Write(text);
    fh.Close();
}
```

The @1 is coming from a database and it's a customer's name. The above code works until I came across a customer name with a forward slash in it, e.g.  "Company A/S".

How do I make this work for customers with the forward slash?

Comment: what system is this trying to create a file on?

Answer (score 7):

Replace any slashes in the customer name with another character (e.g. an underscore).

```
var custname= "@1";
custname = custname.replace(/\//g, '_');
...
```

Note the use of the `g` modifier on the regular expression to ensure that *every* slash character is replaced.

This is also why a regexp is used instead of just `'/'` - the substring version of `String.replace` won't handle repeated occurences.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace (or delete) any characters not allowed by the filesystem.  For example:

```
custname = custname.replace(/[/|&$]/g, '');
```

Comment: Just a note that this would only get the first /

Comment: @highlycaffeinated good call on the extra characters, although `&` is actually allowed on win7, at least.  Not permitted are `<`, `>`, `:`, `|`, `*`, `?` and `"`

Answer (score 0):

If it's Windows you can't have a file name with "/" in it so personally I'd just replace all "/" with something else.

```
var file = "c:/temp/"+ custname.replace(/\//g, "-") + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the file from the customers name as well, so when they have a '/' in their name, the file directory could look something like:

```
var custname= "/isuck";
var file = "c:/temp/"+ custname + ".txt";
```

File would equal:

```
c:/temp//isuck.txt
```

Which wouldn't be a valid file. The SMART move would be to not allow any '/' marks in a customer name, which really doesn't make sense away. Or if they HAVE to put it in that way, remove the '/' before storing it, or replace it with another character.

Answer (score 0):

Store an id, eg a number, for each customer in the database and get the database to return this. Use the number for the filename. If you then need the name do another query.